# Getting 'KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"' when trying to open Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, powerbi

I am trying to import data into PowerBi using a Python script so that I can schedule it to refresh data at regular basis.
I am facing a challenge getting the data from an excel file and receiving the error **'KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml'** in the archive"
' while importing.

When I look into the archive of the xlsx file in the xl folder **there is no file sharedString.xml.** As there are no strings in the excel. the file opens properly in an excel without any issues but not with python.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas
import xlrd
import os
globaltrackerdf = pandas.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Documents\Trackers\Tracker-Global Tracker_V2-2022-06-13.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1",engine="openpyxl")
```

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me: Resave your file using your excel. My file also opened fine in Excel but upon zipping the file and looking inside there was no `sharedStrings.xml`. There seems to be a bug where saving a xlsx might not produce the `sharedStrings.xml` file. I found various ideas about why it might happen but since I don't have access to the client's Excel not sure what caused it.

For extra context on what an XLSX file is, I found this to be helpful: https://www.adimian.com/blog/fast-xlsx-parsing-with-python/